# Grouping points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clustering, concave-hull

I need to group 400 points in 10 groups with 40 points each. The goal is to get the 40 points geographicly together like this:

[image]

Any idea how to do this with QGIS?

Comment: Something goes wrong. The result is not what I expected. I’m looking or something that begins, let’s say, in the upper left point, groups 40 points and begins to group the following 40 points. I try to  create 10 territories with 40 addresses each to organize visits at those addresses and don’t have to travel much far.

Comment: I struggle with this tool. I have set of 478 points and need to create clusters of max size 36 points. When I change "Number of neighbors" to any number, it never creates cluster of given max points. I tried all other QGIS solutions and I can find anything else. Do you have any problems with it? For me this sounds like a simple task, just geographically group points up to 36 points per cluster. So far, it is impossible. When I put 36 as attribute for number of neighbors, result layer have only 1 cluster... Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/149554)

Answer (score 15):

The Concave Hull plugin adds **Shared Nearest Neighbor Clustering** to processing

[image]

[image]

Comment: This workflow does not seem to work any more. In the description of the latest plugin version, it is mentioned "Removed algorithms for processing framework, because the KNN algorithm is already shipped with QGIS". Unfortunately, there is nothing similar to be found. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With QGIS I don't exacly but for example you can use a algorithm about machine learning as "K-Means" where your input is the latitude and longitude and you choose the number of groups and then direcly the algorithm resolv your problem in theses groups with the distance requirement.