# How to cluster point data into equal sized groups

Tags: qgis, clustering, grouping

I need to cluster point data into equal sized groups. I have 180 points and want to create 3 groups each containing 60 points. The groups should contain points which are close to each other. Is there anyway to do this using either ArcGIS or other GIS free software. I would prefer not to use python unless anyone has a link to the script that can be copied and pasted in.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @annesugrue! In ArcGIS, there is the [Grouping Analysis](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/grouping-analysis.htm#GUID-ECAAFD59-7572-4597-8321-C29C94377D06) tool which allows you to group points based on a number of parameters such as proximity, number of nearest neighbours etc. Although I think this is only for the Pro license. Ideally, you should focus your question to one GIS software =)

Comment: Yes I have looked at the Grouping Analysis, however it doesn't allow me to specify the exact number per group.

Comment: Maybe this post might help for QGIS: [How to group points in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159285/how-to-group-points-in-qgis)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question.  By asking for QGIS and/or ArcGIS answers here you are effectively asking two questions.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to focus it on one or the other.

Comment: Yes I have looked at that post, unfortunately the concave hull plugin is broken and does not work.

Comment: @annesugrue concave plugin is my baby ;-) Could you please file an issue concering these installation problem? There are several reason for installation problems in general, most of them discussed on SE. I have running Qgis 2.8.7 and 2.14 on Windows 7, and have not encountered these problems. Yes, on Linux as with all plugins having a GUI. But you cannot specify the exact number of cluster members, only the minimum number for features to be recognized as individual cluster.