# point thinning/point selection based on distance threshold in QGIS/GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, saga

I need to thin a point vector later based on the distances amongst points. So I have a threshold and wish to omit all records but one that is below a distance `D` representing a distance between points. Say `D` points are tree locations `D` is the canopy radius and I want to select/extract/remove all trees within the canopy of another tree.

I have tried 2 approaches unsuccessfully:

1. Distance matrix (QGIS) and I can select points below `D` but can only remove all or none, but I need to have a single remaining one.
2. Buffering the points with `D` and applying the *Select Within* Plugin to select polygons with their centroid within other polygons returns a selection of all polygon because centroids fall inside the other polygons.

How do I remove all records but the first that are closer than `D`?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you really want to have only one single point remaining? What does D relate to, the distances between point neighbors?

Comment: If it does not have to be GRASS-oriented, there is SAGA algorithm which does exactly what you have described.

Comment: You may want to take a look at v.decimate (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.decimate.html) which decimates a point cloud, perhaps useful here as well.

Answer (score 1):

The function Point thinning of SAGA plugin for QGIS does this based on a distance threshold as desired. [A similar question explains this here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233032/reduce-number-of-points-in-polygon)

Answer (score 0):

In the top toolbar: `Vector > Shape Tools > Geodesic Geometry Simplification > Geodesic point decimate`. You can then specify the input layer, specify the minimum distance between points, and save the output layer in specified directory.

[image: Vector > Shape Tools > Geodesic Geometry Simplification > Geodesic point decimate]

Comment: As of 3.20.3, *Geodesic Point Decimate* is found within the *Shape Tools* plugin.