# Automatic polygonising in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, point-in-polygon

I have multiple points and I need to create polygons that consist specific amount of points.

How could i do this?

Comment: He certainly wants to create polygons based on a given points selection ... but what is his logic for grouping these points remains unclear at that stage ... _can u elaborate a bit your question_ ?

Comment: I have thousands of addresses and I want to create polygons with specific amount of addresses (for instance 1000) I know tools like k means clustering or dbscan clustering but i can choose only distance between points (addresses) I would like to chose number of points in polygon

Answer (score 0):

Group the points like:
[Grouping points in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159285/how-to-group-points-in-qgis)

Then run a convex hull. Vector> Geoprocessing Tools> Convex Hull.