# QGIS > Concave Hull plugin > Shared Nearest Neighbor Clustering

Tags: qgis, clustering

I have been using the Concave Hull plugin in QGIS & the Shared Nearest Neighbor Clustering feature.

I am having issues with this plugin, each time I choose the option of "Number of Neighbours" it doesn't seem to work.

This is the same issue DrottTom explains in his post here,

[Grouping points in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159285/grouping-points-in-qgis)

Comment: As a workaround, you could make the point clusters first, using one of several `clustering` tool in the processing toolbox. Then create concave hulls using the `concave hulls (k-nearest neighbor)` algorithm, which allows you to specify a grouping field.