# Performing Grouping Analysis in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clustering, scipy.spatial

Is there a QGIS tool that does the function of http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/grouping-analysis.htm

**MY NEED -** I have about 15,000 points. I need them clustered in batches of about 700 and polygons created for each batch. There will be a central node that it needs to radiate from.

This was asked back in 2013 in [Clustering of multiple raster layers to create sub-regions using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46819/grouping-analysis-of-points-to-divide-a-polygon-into-n-number-of-sub-regions) but there were no replies.

This should look like:

[image]

There is almost a PostGIS (and other) solution in the following but this is now ~4y old
[Identifying clusters in vector point data using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11342/identifying-clusters-in-vector-point-data-using-qgis)

I also had a look at the following but can't find anything that does what I need.
http://opensourcegisblog.blogspot.com.au/2015/03/spatial-analysis-with-qgis-part-i-point.html

**I NEED a result like this.** Is this essentially the [scipy k-means](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.vq.html#module-scipy.cluster.vq) module where the [clustering process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133656/how-to-understand-the-drawbacks-of-k-means) has several issues?

[image]

Comment: I've just added a bounty to the earlier question because I can see that you have put effort into writing this one.  We prefer that the original question is worked on, rather than a duplicate being posted, using the strategies described in http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/what-should-i-do-if-my-question-was-asked-but-there-is-no-accepted-answer-for-t

Comment: @PolyGeo -no worries but is it ok If I edit the original question to incorporate my issues as well. I need not just a copy of the arcgis tool but a model that takes X points and clusters them around a central hub and outputs a polygon for each of the points.

Comment: Yes - I would definitely recommend editing the original.  That user has not visited the site for about 6 months.  However, any edit you make should preserve the intent of that post, while including your content, and at the same time remain highly readable i.e. don't just tack yours on with a dividing line between theirs and yours.  I would probably structure it as mostly theirs followed by "as an example" using mostly yours.  If your additions are not seen by them as an improvement to their question they may roll them back.

Comment: @GeorgeC - Perhaps this post might help: [How to group points in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159285/how-to-group-points-in-qgis)